# Do we have a phrase to express "to form arms in a shape of a cup"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

We have the structure "**cup your hands**" meaning "**to make a shape like a cup with your hands**".

It seems like we don't have the structure "**cup your arms**" to mean "**to make a shape like a cup with your arms**".

Do we have a phrase to express "**to form arms in a shape of a cup**"?

For example, "**cup your arms together so that I can throw the ball into them**"?

Comment: How can you make a cup shape with your arms, when they are long and thin and a cup is round? "Hold out your arms" is the best I can think of (though I know that usually means "spread them out as though inviting someone to hug you").

Comment: To hold something in the manner of your drawing is called *cradling*.  If I wanted to tell someone to do what I see in your drawing I would say, *Hold your arms so you can **cradle** the ball as you catch it.*

Comment: @Tom Who is "we", please?

Comment: @Tom If we did, that would always be “to form arms in the (never a) shape of a cup” and still No, "we" don't.

Comment: The cue I was given when learning to catch this way was 'elbows to sides' or 'elbows together'. This naturally turns the hands up and reduces the hole that a 'cup' has in the middle for the ball to fall through. This is a common way of catching in Australian Rules Football.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, I can't think of a phrase that would be used to describe this. "Cup your arms" might be understood, but is not idiomatic.

The person would probably gesture and say something like:

> Put/hold your arms out like this.

I guess maybe you could say something like:

> Hold your arms out like a <whatever it is you're trying to emulate (maybe "basket"?)>.

But this is not an idiom, it's very much on-the-fly, and perhaps a bit silly sounding, i.e. you'd be less likely to say it in a formal context, more joking around perhaps. And the person would probably make an attempt, and then say something like, "What, like this?", requesting your inspection.

Another one you might possibly hear would be:

> Hold your arms out ready to catch (the ball).

But this would obviously be specific to a catching scenario.

Anyway, the first thing I said, with the gesture, that would be the most common by far in my opinion. If the person wasn't in a position to see your gesturing, there would quite possibly be a lengthy description of precisely what you meant.

Answer (score 12):

To hold something in the manner of your drawing is called **cradling**. If I wanted to tell someone to do what I see in your drawing I would say, *Hold your arms so you can **cradle** the ball as you catch it.*